# Javascript Binding Not working

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I have a new CLI based Angular applicaiton that I am creating.  I have followed the instructions on the ng-bootstrap site.

Installed Bootstrap: npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6

Installed ng-bootstratp: npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Made sure my angular version was up to date "4.1.1"

Setup the app.module.ts correctly (I think)

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FileDataService, FILE_UPLOAD_URL } from './file-data.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FileDetailComponent } from './file-detail/file-detail.component';
import { FileListComponent } from './file-list/file-list.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FileDetailComponent,
    FileListComponent,
    NavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'filelist',
        component: FileListComponent
      }
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [ FileDataService,
      { provide: FILE_UPLOAD_URL, useValue: 'http://localhost:8008' }
      ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The CSS is being applied correclty and looks fine.  The issue is that none of the javascript is getting executed.  For example the toggle for the menu when it goes down to the hamberger does not work.  Alerts that are supposed to be dismissable do not react to clicking the "X".  I am not sure how to fix this.  I don't have any errors in console.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: No, alerts won't close by themselves. The dismissible flag just allows displaying a close icon. How to close alerts is explained in the closable alert demo at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/alert.

Comment: Regarding the hamburger icon in the navbar, there's no ng-bootstrap component for that, so it won't magically do anything either. You can to use the NgbCollapse directive (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse) to make the menu collapsed/visible. You think to seem that ng-bootstrap is a drop-in replacement for bootstrap's jquery-based JS, and that you can just use the documentation of bootstrap and have ng-bootstrap do the same thing. That's not what ng-bootstrap is.

Comment: JB Nizet - so are you saying that the javascript to close the alert is not there and I have to program it?  That seems weird when you just use bootstrap out of the box and the alerts work just fine and I can dismiss the alert by clicking on the "X".  As I read over that I would assume that if I use this call `<ngb-alert type="danger" dismissable="true">Test Dismissable</ngb-alert>` then I would get a test alert and be able to dismiss it with a mouse click.  I re-read over the page that you linked to but still could not figure out a solution.  Thanks very much for your input.

Comment: JB Nizet - I posted before seeing your second post.  Thanks for some additional information.  I think I see what you are saying now.  I will go back and review how these are setup and see if I can get it working.

Comment: closing an alert is trivial. See the demo. The idea is that the component doesn't have any idea when the alert should be or become visible. If you use `*ngIf="alertVisible"` to display an alert when your functional component sets alertVisible to true, then closing the alert should make this `alertVisible` flag to false. The alert component can't guess that that should happen when closing the alert. So it lets you control what makes the alert visible or invisible.

Comment: JB Nizet - I was able to go back and read through the documentationa and with the helpful informaiton you provided, was able to get this to work.  I appreciate you taking the time to answer the questions.  How can I give you credit, do you want to copy the comments into an answer and I can give you credit.  Thanks very much for your assistance.

Comment: Don't worry about that. I'm happy to have helped. You can post an answer by yourself explaining what you learnt.